# Flutter Syncfusion SfDataGrid Problem with single tap editing

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

The problem is that when I try to edit a cell I need to use 2 tap, first tap to select and the second to edit. The Problem is that I config
`editingGestureType: EditingGestureType.tap` 
as suggests documentation.
I want that editing appear at the first tap. There is something in config which is wrong?
I add a video here to better understand: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tvJeT5BWOoLifdBUNMbBs5JpmDF9ogl2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't recommend you do this, because Syncfusion's plugins all require money for commercial use.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Thank you for that, I know it is a not open source code but it is needed for this project. I think there won't be any problem to re-use my code because is very similar to what is inside the documentation https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/editing which is free.

I need that someone can help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

With version 21.2.5 there seems to be a clear improvement and editing works correctly almost always. I must therefore deduce that it is a problem of the dependency and not of the code itself